# Why can't I pipe a password into mysql non-interactively?

Tags: mysql

I want to run mysql client, giving the password non-interactively.

The standard solution is this

```
mysql -u root -e "foo" -p < password_file
```

but my situation is this

```
produce_password | mysql -u root -p
```

Here, mysql prompts for a password, even though data is being piped in. (Yes, `produce_password` is emitting data; `echo foo | mysql` behaves the same way.)

The Internet seems to think the above should work, but the fact is it doesn't. The workaround would be

```
produce_password > password_file
mysql -u root -p < password_file
rm password_file
```

But let's say I don't want to do this (e.g. policy demands that this password never be written to the disk)

How can I make mysql take the password from the input process without prompting, as it would for a file?

Comment: Related: [What's a secure alternative to using a MySQL password on the command line?](http://serverfault.com/questions/476228/whats-a-secure-alternative-to-using-a-mysql-password-on-the-command-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With thanks to fancyPants for explaining the cause, here is a solution which meets my requirements. (The encrypted `.mylogin.cnf` with `mysql_config_editor` isn't right for me, but thanks.)

To satisfy the security policy, mount `/ramfs` as a ramfs temporary file system. Assume file permissions are suitably restrictive.

```
ramdir="/ramfs"
cnf="$(mktemp "$ramdir/this-script-name-XXXXX")"
pw="$(produce_password)"

cat >"$cnf" <<EOF
[client]
user=root
password="$pw"
EOF

mysql --defaults-extra-file="$cnf" -e 'select 1'

rm "$cnf"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to explain this, but when you pipe something, the stdout of the first program is forwarded to the stdin of the second program. You somehow confuse this, with the command line or whatever. You can pipe something to mysql, of course, but whatever you pipe is handled **after** you've authenticated yourself.

The solution would be

```
mysql -u root -p$(produce_password)
```

This generates your password with whatever program you have there and puts it in the right place on your commandline (my english is bad, can't explain better). When you have it in a file you could do

```
mysql -u root -p$(cat file)
```

I don't know, why you want to do it this way anyway, but you might be interested in having an encrypted file with your credentials, that you can use to log in without specifying a password. Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html).

Answer (score 1):

the problem with that is the password shows up in the process list.
But you can do this.

```
mysql --defaults-file=<(echo '[client]'; echo 'user=USERNAME'; echo "password=$mysqlpassword";)
```

It shows up in the process list like this.

```
mysql --defaults-file=/dev/fd/63
```

so the `<()` creates a file handle to the output of your commands.
This works with command line options that are expecting a file.

Comment: So you have the password in an environment variable? How secure is that?

Comment: Echoing the password is bad idea. The echo command can be seen in process table for fraction of second with the variable resolved (effectivelly showing the password). Further reading: https://www.netmeister.org/blog/passing-passwords.html

Comment: Actually, modern shells provide a shell builtin for echo (and printf, which is way more useful).

Comment: @spraff but you in your answer also using environment variable. How secure it is?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to declare [the environment variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/environment-variables.html) `MYSQL_PWD`.

Example:

```
$ export MYSQL_PWD=$(produce the password if required)
$ mysql -h example.org -u username
```

Remember you should not use `-p` in this case.

Comment: From the linked doc:  "Use of MYSQL_PWD to specify a MySQL password must be considered extremely insecure and should not be used" and also "MYSQL_PWD is deprecated as of MySQL 8.0; expect it to be removed in a future version of MySQL"

Comment: thank you very much, @snakecharmerb. It was a really easy way to do it, but if it is going to be deprecated, I need to review several scripts XD